# Unable to import numpy even though PYTHONPATH is correctly set

Tags: python, numpy, pythonpath

Using pip I installed numpy in my home directory. I added this path to PYTHONPATH. But whenever I do "import numpy" it imports the numpy installed in the system folder. See output below:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Apps/users/hussaif1/python27

root@lustwz99:/root # python
Python 2.7.8 (default, May 19 2015, 02:50:14)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.version
<module 'numpy.version' from '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/version.pyc'>
>>>
```

`root@lustwz99:/root # ll /Apps/users/hussaif1/python27
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 hussaif1 hussaif1 4096 Aug 16 09:25 ./
drwx------ 49 hussaif1 hussaif1 4096 Aug 16 09:20 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 hussaif1 hussaif1 4096 Aug 16 09:38 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  3 hussaif1 hussaif1 4096 Aug 16 09:25 lib64/`

I manually created the python27 folder and used this command to install numpy there:

pip install --install-option="--prefix=/Apps/users/hussaif1/python27" --ignore-installed numpy

Comment: Maybe you could `import sys` and include the output of calling `sys.path` to your example. This would help investigating the lookup order python uses.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what PYTHONPATH actually means. Where does this python27 directory come from? Did you create it with a virtualenv for example? Does the python27/bin folder contain a `python` executable ?

Comment: Thanks, here is the output from sys.path:

>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Apps/users/hussaif1/python27', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',

Answer (score 0):

This is very popular problem. To solve this I recommend using [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). Using virtualenv will enable you to easily manage different version of the installed packages. Also it's extremely easy to learn and use - basically you should be fine after 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. My understanding was one can use the PYTHONPATH to point to non-default locations of installed modules.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the full path to the site-packages: